# What kind of pointer should I use here?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on an old large code base with a colleague. The codebase uses a significant number of `std::shared_ptr` and previous developers had a fondness for long property names (`m_first_username` for example).

Some methods in our code access a number of those properties so our code tends to be very verbose:

`if (m_first_username->isSomethingOrOther() || m_second_username->isOtherOrSomething()...`

So to make the code more readable my colleague wants to use more `std::shared_ptr &` with local scope:

`const std::shared_ptr<...> &tmp = m_first_username->returnsASharedPtr()
tmp->isSomethingOrOther();`

Something I disagree with because of the shared pointer use count.

What is the best way to make this code more readable? Keeping using constant references to `shared_ptr`, use `std::weak_ptr` or live with the long lines of code?

Comment: Another option is to just use a `shared_ptr` here as well. I'm guessing this code does not need to be high performance (use of smart pointers is an indication for this), and this will not affect too much

Comment: If threading is not a concern, I'd just do `auto tmp = m_first_username;`

Comment: You consider `tmp->isSomethingOrOther()` to be more readable than `m_first_username->isSomethingOrOther()`? Can you explain that logic?

Comment: I personally do not see what's wrong with the verbosity of that code - it looks very much like a lot of the production code I've been exposed to in the past 15 years.  If you're really set on possibly making the code *less* readable by aliasing then CookiePLMonster's suggestion seems reasonable to me.

Comment: `m_first_username` looks like a reasonable name. There is no way for introduction of weird temporary reference to shared ptr with meaningless name `tmp` to improve readability.

Comment: The proper way to rename a variable is `auto &new_name = old_name;`. Expect that to get completely optimized out.

Comment: In this situation I would favor a raw pointer over a shared pointer *reference* tbh. `auto tmp = m_first_username->returnsASharedPtr().get();`. Unless you actually need to call shared pointer functions I don't see what it adds other than a possible extra redirection.

Comment: Do you have a business reason (not a technical reason) for changing working and tested code?

Comment: Looks like you are simply overusing the shared_ptr, instead of trying to patch your code by doing these tricks, you could wonder why this method should not simply return a reference/raw pointer to the instance.

Comment: @nwp I don't. It's a compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @nwp's comment -the proper way to alias a variable name locally would be:

```
auto& v1 = m_first_user_name;
```

If you want to go the route of the "returnAsSharedPointer" you posted in the question, what you'd want to use in the classes of m_first_user_name and m_second user_name is the standard C++ [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

On the whole, though it's primarily opinion-based, I believe you'll find that most experienced C++ developers will find the new code *less* readable than the old code.  There is nothing wrong with long, descriptive variable names.